# Compare the first five elements of a column to the rest

Tags: awk, filter

I hope you can help me to fix this problem.

I want to compare the first five elements of a column to the rest elements (column by column).

- If the first 5 elements are equal --> continue
- If the first 5 elements are equal, and different to the rest, print these columns

The table has more than 100 columns and 12 rows, the table is separated by TABS.

Example input:

```
Jhon	Laura	Ben	Chris	Dan	Tom
Jhon	Laura	Ben	Lion	Dan	Tom
Jhon	Laura	Ben	Chris	Dan	Tom
Jhon	Laura	Ben	Chris	Dan	Tom
Jhon	Laura	Ben	Chris	Dan	Tom
Dave	Laura	Taylor	Chris	Dona	Sara
Dave	Laura	Harvey	Chris	Dan	Sara
```

Desired output:

```
Jhon	Ben	Tom
Jhon	Ben	Tom
Jhon	Ben	Tom
Jhon	Ben	Tom
Jhon	Ben	Tom
Dave	Taylor	Sara
Dave	Harvey	Sara
```

I really appreciate all your ideas and comments,

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's better to operate on rows (lines). Tools like `awk` operate on one line at a time. To convert your columns to rows (i.e. to transpose) use [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html#Transpose). Then `awk` can do proper tests for each line separately, print it or not. At the end use `datamash` again to transpose the result to your original format:

```
<data datamash transpose | awk '{
    for (i=2; i<=5; i++) if ($1!=$i) next
    for (i=6; i<=NF; i++) if ($1==$i) next
    print
}' | datamash transpose
```

The logic explained:

- The first `for` skips the line and starts over if any of the fields 2..5 is different than the field number 1. All 5 fields being equal is the only possibility that allows the program to continue to the next line of code.
- The second `for` skips the line and starts over if any of the following fields is the same as the first one.
- If the program passed beyond both `for`s, then this means no contradiction to your criteria was found at all. Only then the whole line is printed.

Notes:

- In the original problem (without transposing) you need to read the next line only if there's at least one column that hasn't contradicted your criteria yet. Depending on data, it's possible all columns can be declared no-match just after reading few first rows. In such case the algorithm can exit quickly and print nothing at all. But `datamash transpose` needs to read and process the entire file (or stream) regardless of the data. In this context my solution is suboptimal.
- Just in case `datamash` isn't available, there's an `awk` solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1729980/10765659).

Answer (score 0):

We need to transpose the columns to rows, then run a regex check on what lines to print. Those that have first five elements same should not see the same element again further down. Finally re transpose the result to get the desired output.

HTH.

```
rs -T  inp |
perl -lane 'print if "@F" =~ /^(\S+)(?: \1){4}(?: (?:(?!\1(?=(?: |$))).)+)+$/' |
rs -T
```

**Output:**

```
Jhon    Ben     Tom
Jhon    Ben     Tom
Jhon    Ben     Tom
Jhon    Ben     Tom
Jhon    Ben     Tom
Dave    Taylor  Sara
Dave    Harvey  Sara
```